# How to query database and return single row only

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to do simple projects to learn more. I've done researching, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. Perhaps, my program is not properly structured, but here it goes:

***THIS BLOCK WILL VALIDATE IF THE ENTERED EMPLOYEE ID ALREADY EXISTS IN DATABASE. THIS IS CALLED IN A SERVLET***

```
public boolean login(String employeeID) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "select count(*) as count from employees where emp_id=?";
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setString(1, employeeID);

    rs = statement.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        count = rs.getInt("count");
    }

    rs.close();

    if (count == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

/* METHOD BELOW ITERATES THE FIELDS FROM MYSQL DATABASE, BUT IT DISPLAYS ALL OF IT. 
I JUST WANT TO GET A SINGLE ROW MATCHING THE EMPLOYEE ID PARAMETER ENTERED.*/

public List<EmployeeNumber> _list() throws SQLException {

    List<EmployeeNumber> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from employees";
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        EmployeeNumber emp = new EmployeeNumber();
        emp.setEmployeeNumber(rs.getString(1));
        emp.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
        emp.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
        emp.setEmail(rs.getString(4));
        emp.setDepartment(rs.getString(5));
        emp.setFirstApprover(rs.getString(6));
        emp.setSecondApprover(rs.getString(7));
        result.add(emp);
    }

    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
    }

    if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }

    return result;
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with my SQL Query statement but I can't figure out how to fix it.

So in a nutshell, when I submit the employee ID from JSP page, it will validate if that exists, and if it does, I want to display all the column fields within the same row where this employee ID is positioned. How do I do that? Results will be displayed on another JSP page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're first counting how many employees have the given ID. Then you're selecting *all* the rows from the employee table.

Skip the first query, and only use the second one, but by adding a where clause, just as you did with the first query:

```
select * from employees where emp_id=?
```

Then after you've bound the parameter (as you did for the first query), test if there is a row returned:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // get the data, and return an EmployeeNumber instance containing the data
}
else {
    // no employee with the given ID exists: return null
}
```

Note that the method shouldn't return a `List<EmployeeNumber>`, but an `EmployeeNumber`, since you only want to get 1 employee from the table.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll try this out and hopefully I can make it work.

Comment: So I've tried this out... I completely get rid of the _list method and put them all in my boolean login method - it works and validates fine. But how do I pass those fields to a JSP page using JSTL forEach loop? I was able to do it using List, but again, it displays all data from the table. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried <jsp:useBean> and set class="beans.EmployeeNumber" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

```
String sql = "select count(*) as count from employees where emp_id=?";
statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, employeeID);

int count = statement.ExecuteScalar();

if (count == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}

}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can also set a breakpoint and step through your code and see where the exception is being thrown. That would help us, knowing the exception message and where it's breaking.